# Plotting data on maps

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, maps

I am trying to write a Windows Form Application to display data on maps. I can write the data successfully if I enter it manually but  am facing some issues while uploading the data via Excel file. I have stored Latitude and Longitude in an Excel file and I am reading that file. My code is reading the data perfectly but it is not getting plotted. However if I store only one Lat/Long in that Excel file it does plot that. Here is my code for manual data feeding, which is working fine.

```
private void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lat = txtlat.Text;

            try
            {
                StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();
                queryaddress.Append("https://www.here.com/search/");

                if (street != string.Empty)
                {
                    queryaddress.Append(street );
                }

                webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
```

When I read data from Excel file one by one it is not getting plotted. Here is the code:

```
private void btnmap_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 1; i <=20; i++)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
                tb_display_content.Text = excel_getValue("A" + i);
                string lat = tb_display_content.Text;
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();

                    queryaddress.Append("https://www.here.com/search/");

                    if (lat != string.Empty)
                    {
                        queryaddress.Append(lat );
                    }

                    webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
                }
            }
        }
```

What is wrong in this code? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

1. Take `StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();` outside of the loop
2. Clear the `queryaddress` for the next loop

That should take care of your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. It looks like you're not building your http query string properly. The URL of the service you're trying to use is...

```
https://www.here.com/search/testing?x=ep&map=41.56144,-71.59227,12,normal
```

Where "testing" is the search term and "map=41.56144,-71.59227" is the center position of the map. In order to have this display a lat/long properly you need to replicate this and substitute your lat, long and search term. Something like...

```
var searchTerm = "kittens";
var lat = "41.2312";
var lon = "-72.102";
var finalURL = string.format(@"https://www.here.com/search/{0}?x=ep&map={1},{2},12,normal",searchTerm, lat, lon);
```

Your second problem is that on your Excel example, you're defining a URL, requesting that URL, displaying that URL, and then repeating the process every 3000ms. That code will only display the last point on your Excel spreadsheet once it finishes running (if it runs at all...hint...it won't because of your first issue).

Here's some recommended reading for you: [HTTP Query Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)